# How can I turn off the autodim feature on my Linux laptop so it actually stays off?

Tags: linux, laptop, linux-mint, power-management, laptop-display

I have a vintage GD8000 laptop running Linux Mint 18.3, and I'm having trouble turning off the autodim feature.

I have turned off autodimming in Mint's preferences, and I have also turned it off in the GD8000's BIOS. However, the screen still dims after 90 seconds of input inactivity.

Is there a way I can turn off the autodim feature so it actually stays off?

**--UPDATE--**

I've observed a little more closely, and the screen is not precisely being *dimmed*, in the sense of backlighting remaining on but being at a lower intensity. The backlighting is turning off completely. (But the screen is still "painted" and can be partially seen in bright light.) I suspect this is not a Linux issue.

Answer (score 3):

The answer will differ depending on what desktop environment you're using. Since you're on Linux Mint, I figured that it's pretty likely you're in a Desktop Environment that uses `gsettings` (like Gnome or Cinnamon).

There are a few options you can change on the command line:

- Try to set the brightness that the 'dim' function uses to full brightness  (this might make your screen *brighter* when it dims)

  > `gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power idle-brightness 100`
- Try to turn of auto-dimming altogether

  > `gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power idle-dim false`
- Make the criteria for 'inactive' 0, meaning your screen never goes inactive.

  > `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.session idle-delay 0`

Any of the above options can also be changed graphically using `dconf-editor`

> `sudo apt-get install dconf-editor && dconf-editor`

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Superuser and Stackexchange! For my information, do the commands work for all login sessions, or for the current login session only, so I need to put them in `~/.login` or such?

Comment: @JonathanHayward Thank you! Any setting you modify through the settings-daemon will persist forever unless you change it, or Gnome removes it in an update or something.

Comment: Ok. I've made those changes, and it appears to be back to old tricks. It dims after 90 seconds.